# Enforce a base class implements a specific interface

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, interface

Is there a way for a child class to make sure the parent class implements a specific interface?

```
public interface ISomeInterface<T>
{
   T DoSomething();
}

public class Parent : ISomeInterface<SomeType>
{
   SomeType DoSomething(){}
}

public class Child : Parent
{
     //Enforce the parent implements ISomeInterface<T>.
     var foo = DoSomething();  
}
```

Comment: that's not how oop works.  that relationship is the other way-a-round in that the parent can define an interface or abstract  method

Comment: define it like `public class Parent : ISomeInterface`

Comment: @SirRufo agreed, have just forget to read the details

Comment: @SirRufo Sure but how can the child enforce that the parent is actually implementing the `ISomeInterface`.

Comment: I told you the **only** one possibility to enforce the Parent class to implement that interface in exactly this scenario. There is not more.

Comment: @SirRufo - i think you have mis-read the question given you comment

Comment: in short the answer is `No`. The child has no way to enforce anything upon the parent.

Comment: @Jazb I did not misread the question - I made a **comment** about the only possibility to have `Parent` implement `ISomeInterface` - and my **comment** is **not an answer** to this question, it is a **comment**. If it would be an answer I had posted it in the answer section (easy thing here on SO) - And because it is the only possibility, the answer is NO - it is not possible to **enforce it from Child class**

Comment: ok fair enough - probable subtleties lost in translation - all good!

Comment: You don't need to *enforce* anything, the CLR will do it for you. If you call `DoSomething` then the code will not compile (or be loaded) unless `Parent` does support that method with that exact signature.